What is the image's actual size if printed in paper by printer?
Simple formula to calculate the actual size:
actual size (in inches) = pixels / resolution

If the width is 600 pixels and resolution is 300,then size = 600/300 = 2 inches.
List all the elements of the sample.webp file.
identify  -verbose   sample.webp
Image:
  Filename: sample.webp
  Format: WEBP (WebP Image Format)
  Mime type: image/webp
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 514x402+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Type: TrueColor
  Base type: Undefined
  Endianness: Undefined
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 206628
    Red:
      min: 22  (0.0862745)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 247.292 (0.969773)
      standard deviation: 29.3655 (0.115159)
      kurtosis: 26.7614
      skewness: -5.10833
      entropy: 0.327231
    Green:
      min: 23  (0.0901961)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 249.128 (0.976973)
      standard deviation: 26.3003 (0.103138)
      kurtosis: 31.2312
      skewness: -5.52078
      entropy: 0.246981
    Blue:
      min: 20  (0.0784314)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 249.658 (0.979052)
      standard deviation: 24.4937 (0.0960539)
      kurtosis: 35.2188
      skewness: -5.80532
      entropy: 0.248523
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 20  (0.0784314)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 248.693 (0.975266)
      standard deviation: 26.7198 (0.104784)
      kurtosis: 30.85
      skewness: -5.46476
      entropy: 0.274245
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Background color: white
  Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
  Matte color: grey74
  Transparent color: black
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 514x402+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: Undefined
  Orientation: Undefined
  Properties:
    date:create: 2024-04-09T05:54:16+00:00
    date:modify: 2024-04-09T05:53:45+00:00
    signature: 92c4c0125001357b35a6721035c381606c4b03ea9842d2eb5fe726bbeb701601
  Artifacts:
    filename: sample.webp
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 13716B
  Number pixels: 206628
  Pixels per second: 35.6846MB
  User time: 0.010u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.005
  Version: ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 Q16 x86_64 2021-01-25 https://imagemagick.org

How can get sample.webp's resolution info?
What is the image's actual size (in inches) if printed in paper by printer?

You can print an image at any size you like. DPI is only relevant if you are expecting to print at a particular resolution and want specific (high quality) results no matter where you print your image. Images only intended for viewing on a screen will have different assumptions about DPI to ones intended for printing. Your image resolution is Geometry: 514x402 and it does not appear to have any information about printed DPI. Printing at 300 DPI will result in an image somewhere around 1.7 inches, while printing at 150DPI will give somewhere closer 3.4 inches with worse resolution.

Printing an image in its true and exact resolution will normally result in a very small image on the page. This is because the printer's page is much larger than the screen. In general, printing is done in a larger resolution that is proportional to the relation between the screen DPI and the page DPI, except for very large images or ones that were intended for the printer.

To get closer to reality...
PPI - Pixels Per Inch, how many image-pixels you get on paper when printing it.
DPI - Dots Per Inch in images is non-sensical. Only meaningful if you INTEND the image to be a certain width in Inches. If a DPI value is given in image metadata, it often has no meaning in practice - creating an image that has low resolution if scaled accordingly (on screen or paper).
Some software e.g. Photoshop, sloppily applies "300 DPI" or even "72 DPI" to mages where you have not defined it yourself, manually. Software DOES adjust the value for e.g. resizing operations.
DPI - Dots Per Inch for printed images on paper; PRINTER dots are single color. Pixels placed on paper by printers consists of e.g. an matrix of dots,  selected from the available fixed colors, maybe 36x36 dots...
UNLESS you have an sublimation-based printer (which I exclude from this text).
Resolution - The amount of detail you have in the subject of your image. So; Your Image's pixel-resolution is one thing. Further; If you have placed your image on paper, with resizing it in the process; then it has an entirely new resolution.
Pixels - has no inherit "resolution", the IMAGE resolution (subject detail) depends on how it was captured; which camera (sensor, film), which lens, what distance, which aperture, ...
With a SHARP image (single pixel to next pixel) you can print it at any size; if the viewer looks at it from an APPROPRIATE distance it will still appear sharp.
Every pixel in such a printed image would correspond to an MAXIMUM angle of 1/30° for the eye, at the correct distance.
